# JobRunr is running all jobs at the same time, instead of running them one by one with some time pause between them

Tags: java, scheduler, distributed, jobrunr

I have a problem which I do not really know how to solve, as the docs for JobRunr are very limited.

On production environment I have few nodes and during the night I am queueing multiple jobs at once in a loop.

**My understanding is that, I would see those jobs taken one-by-one on the same node**, especially with single worker configured.
Instead, all of the jobs are started in the same second, on the same node even ;)
It causes a big performance drop, so I need to at least split those jobs apart in few minutes preferably.

So, I did write a test for that:

```
class JobRunrTest extends BaseContextTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobRunrTestStorageService jobRunrTestStorageService;

    @Value("${org.jobrunr.background-job-server.poll-interval-in-seconds}")
    private int pollInterval;

    private final long jobs = 5;

    @Test
    void testJobsAreRunSequentially() {
        // Given
        for (int i = 0; i < jobs; i++) {
            BackgroundJob.enqueue(() -> jobRunrTestStorageService.add());
        }

        // When
        await()
            .atMost(jobs * pollInterval, SECONDS)
            .pollInterval(pollInterval, SECONDS)
            .until(() -> jobRunrTestStorageService.getStorage().size() == jobs);

        // Then
        var jobResults = jobRunrTestStorageService.getStorage();
        for (int i = 1; i < jobs; i++) {
            var timeDiff = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(jobResults.get(i - 1), jobResults.get(i));
            assertThat(timeDiff).isGreaterThan(1); // First I want to reach 1 SECOND diff with jobs
        }
    }
}
```

Where the autowired JobRunrTestStorageService is a simple class like this:

```
@Service
public class JobRunrTestStorageService {

    @Getter
    private final List<LocalTime> storage = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add() {
        storage.add(LocalTime.now());
    }
}
```

Of course, the test is on a single node, as I still need to move apart the jobs even on a single node. At least that be my 1st goal.

Job runr configs that I have:

```
org.jobrunr.job-scheduler.enabled=true
org.jobrunr.background-job-server.enabled=true
org.jobrunr.background-job-server.worker-count=1
org.jobrunr.background-job-server.poll-interval-in-seconds=15 # 5 minutes on prod
```

Could you to point me in the right direction?
Thanks!

Any code snippet is welcome as well :)

Comment: Hhhmm, this is strange - it indeed should only process job per job if you configure the worker-count to 1. Could you create an issue with a link to a github repo that reproduces the issue?